# Is there an OS X tool that allows cropping with a particular aspect ratio?

Tags: macos, software-rec, photos, crop, image-editing

I'm spoiled by FastStone on the PC. I'm looking for decent freeware/shareware for Mac OS X that will allow basic photo editing, particularly something that lets me pick a crop size or aspect ratio by entering in numbers rather than just a freehand crop (I need to make sure it's 8.5"x11" aspect ratio).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out how to do it in [Gimp](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-crop.html#id3092982).

Answer (score 1):

I've liked what I used of [Acorn](http://www.flyingmeat.com/acorn/) before my trial ran out, and it has the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iPhoto to manage your photos it does offer the ability to crop using a specific aspect ratio when you choose Edit.

Comment: one of these days I will try out iPhoto (came w/ my mac!) -- I'm just a little leery until I can make sure I can use it w/o copying or moving all my photos into a different set of folders.

Comment: @Jason S: Your question from last month says that it's doable without messing with your folders: http://superuser.com/questions/1883/using-iphoto-without-copying-images